# How To Storing The Frame Range In Python?

Tags: python, timestamp, media-player, face-recognition, face-detection

so i have a project to make a simple media player with detection and recognition feature but i get stuck with with the system do recognition process it will store a frame when the system detect adn recognized a person for example in frame 164 the system detect and recognized a person, the system will keep that frame and continue to do recognition process until maybe in frame 185 the system not detect and recognized that person anymore in frame the system will stop storing the frame. so the system will keep a frame from 164 - 185 and from that frame system will convert it into timestamp that will display in media player and for now i still got an issue because i can't storing the frame where the system detect and recognized a person.

this my recognition process code:

```
def recognition_faces(self):
    # train the data using all the images in the dataset
    faces, labels = training("Training-Data")

    face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

    # convert labels (list) to numpy array as LBPH Face Recognizer needs a numpy array as its second argument
    labels = np.array(labels)
    face_recognizer.train(faces, labels)

    names = {
        1: 'a',
        2: 'b',
        3: 'c',
        4: 'd',
        5: 'e',
        6: 'f',
        7: 'g',
        8: 'h',
        9: 'i',
        10: 'j'
    }
    input_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Input Folder")
    if input_folder:
        output_folder = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Output Folder")

        # Flag To Track Successful Recognition
        all_frames_processed_successfully = True

        for image_files in os.listdir(input_folder):
            if not image_files.startswith('.'):
                test_image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, image_files)
                image = cv2.imread(test_image_path)

                cropped_faces, coordinates = Perform_Face_Detection(test_image_path)
                if cropped_faces is None:
                    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_files)
                    cv2.imwrite(output_path, image)
                    continue

                confidence_threshold = 150
                max_confidence = 150

                recognized_faces = []
                recognized_names = []
                unrecognized_faces = []

                # Initialize the dictionary for each new image
                self.person_frame_ranges = {}

                for i in range(len(cropped_faces)):
                    (x, y, width, height) = coordinates[i]

                    cropped_face = cropped_faces[i]

                    label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(cropped_face)

                    if confidence < confidence_threshold:
                        if label in names:
                            confidence_percent = 100
                            recognized_name = names[label]
                            recognized_faces.append(cropped_face)
                            recognized_names.append(recognized_name)

                            if recognized_name in self.person_frame_ranges:
                                self.person_frame_ranges[recognized_name]["end"] = i
                            else:
                                self.person_frame_ranges[recognized_name] = {"start": i, "end": i}


                        else:
                            confidence_percent = max(0, (max_confidence - confidence) / max_confidence * 100)
                            recognized_name = "Unknown"
                            unrecognized_faces.append(cropped_face)

                    else:
                        confidence_percent = max(0, (max_confidence - confidence) / max_confidence * 100)
                        recognized_name = "Unknown"
                        unrecognized_faces.append(cropped_face)

                    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                    cv2.putText(image, f"{str(recognized_name)}", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2,
                                (255, 255, 255), 2)

                output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_files)
                cv2.imwrite(output_path, image)

                # Display recognized faces and names in the GUI
                self.show_recognized_faces(recognized_faces, recognized_names, np.array(confidence_percent), self.table_recognized_faces)

                # Display The Recognized And Unrecognized Faces In The GUI
                self.show_unrecognized_faces(unrecognized_faces, self.table_unrecognized_faces)

                # Print frame ranges for debugging
                for recognized_name, frame_range in self.person_frame_ranges.items():
                    start_frame = frame_range["start"]
                    end_frame = frame_range["end"]
                    print(f"Recognized Name: {recognized_name}")
                    print(f"Frame Range: {start_frame} - {end_frame}")

        # Display a messagebox when all frames are processed and the recognition is successful
        if all_frames_processed_successfully:
            messagebox.showinfo("Face Recognition", "Recognition Complete")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Face Recognition", "Output folder not selected")
```